# if im making a Development Journal For a Tron Fanfiction

Tags: support

if im making a tron project (Creative story/comic book)- using stack exchange /

How best is it for me to present a development diary with external links?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you'd make a creative story/comic book using a Q&A site...

Answer (score 4):

I don't think StackExchange, at least not *this* stack, would be the right tool for that. If you have specific on-topic questions, feel free to ask them here, but I don't think you should try to create a development diary here.

Perhaps the [Writers Stack](https://writers.stackexchange.com/) can be of help.

Comment: This question was closed off by community without answering my question. The user was polite and constructive

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link to an external site, which you think others would be interested that participate on this site, and said site is not likely to advertise for the site, then your best bet is to use the [community ads](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3239/community-promotion-ads-2014). But I don't think your site would work for that.

The next suggestion is to put a link in your profile. You can't post the link around the site, but as you come to make content on the various SE sites, you could get people to click on your profile, and learn what things you are interested in.

Lastly, there is the site blog. This would not work for posting your entire project history, but you might convince the powers that be to let you write a single blog article on your project, if they deem it worthy enough.