# Will we have Community Promotion Ads for 2015?

Tags: discussion

Related: [Community Promotion Ads 2014](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3239/community-promotion-ads-2014)

Will we be doing community promotion ads this year, for 2015? I know I'd like to and I'm guessing a few others out there might want to as well. I asked several times in chat, but didn't get any responses.

Mods, may we do ads this year, please?

If so, do they *have* to be brand new designs, or could we recycle one or two previous designs that people liked? Or could we take an old ad and update it with new colors, perhaps a new font, etc?

The first of the year is right around the corner!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, yeah.  It's a thing that SE does on an annual basis.  We mods aren't really involved, SE themselves take care of it.  They'll make a 2015 post in the next month or two.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Add for Arqade targeting SF]

This *screams* for a return add. I don't frequent [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), so I don't know if there already is one.

Answer (score 1):

We start the cycle every December. Usually I try to do it at the start but sometimes it might be a later week, but December's the period that we'll go and refresh every Community Promotions Ad thread on all of the sites.

As a helpful way to keep on top of this, we include this information on the cycle, as well as additional suggestions regarding recycling ads and such, [the threads contain a section "Why do we reset the ads every year?"](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3239/community-promotion-ads-2014) which granted isn't much but it's a good place to refresh on how to approach the process.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll go and read about recycling ads and resetting them, etc. Appreciate your input :)